# Datetime format not accepted, did I mean .at?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to sort an excel file by datetime. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

dagStart = datetime.strptime(str(date.today())+' 06:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dagEind = datetime.strptime(str(date.today())+' 23:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

data = pd.read_excel('inzamelbestand.xlsx', index_col=9) 

data = data.loc[data['ingezameldop'].dt.time.between(dagStart.time(), dagEind.time())]

data.to_excel("oefenexcel.xlsx")
```

When I run it, it gives the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Inzamelhelden\orden.py", line 10, in <module>
    data = data.loc[data['ingezameldop'].dt.time.between(dagStart.time(), dagEind.time())]
  File "C:\Users\Inzamelhelden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5907, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "C:\Users\Inzamelhelden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py", line 183, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Inzamelhelden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\accessors.py", line 513, in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. Did you mean: 'at'?
```

It seems to me that the datetime format is not accepted, but how would i go about solving this?

Comment: What is `print (type(data['ingezameldop'].iat[0]))` ?

Answer (score 0):

You likely have strings and should convert [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
data = data.loc[pd.to_datetime(data['ingezameldop'])
                  .dt.time.between(dagStart.time(), dagEind.time())]
```

Or if you don't mind having datetime type in the output:

```
data['ingezameldop'] = pd.to_datetime(data['ingezameldop'])
# then as you did
data = data.loc[data['ingezameldop'].dt.time.between(dagStart.time(), dagEind.time())]
```

Answer (score 0):

First is necessary test what is `type` of column `ingezameldop`:

```
print (type(data['ingezameldop'].iat[0]))
```

If it is `time` use:

```
df = data[pd.to_datetime(data['ingezameldop'].between(dagStart.time(), dagEind.time())]
```

If `object` or `time` with [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) for `DatetimeIndex` use:

```
data['ingezameldop'] = pd.to_datetime(data['ingezameldop'].astype(str))
df = data.set_index('ingezameldop').between_time('06:00:00', '23:00:00')
```

Comment: I had not considered that the excel sheet is not to format.. thanks. Anyway, now that i fixed this part I'm running the code; but it is not sorting out the rows between the times. Do you have any idea what might be causing the problem?

Comment: @kucb - what is `print (type(data['ingezameldop'].iat[0]))` ?